# How to pronounce "tableaux"?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology, young-tableaux, pronunciation

How do you pronounce **[Young tableaux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau)**? Does it sound just like its singular form?

Comment: yes, just like its singular form

Comment: @stefan: Not in English.

Comment: I am happy enough if it is not pronounced Tab-lox.  About the plural indication, I might not be upset by an $s$ sound.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : OK, I'll say "tab-lee-uks" and you'll be "happy enough".

Comment: Just make sure you _never_ write "tableaux" when you mean only one of them. For some mysterious reason (probably distraction by questions of (non-)pronunciation) about half the English-speaking authors make this error at some point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on whether you’re pronouncing it in French or in English. In French *tableau* and *tableaux* are pronounced the same; in English *tableaux* is pronounced as if it were spelled *tableaus*, with a /z/ at the end. In fact, the plural can be spelled either *tableaux* or *tableaus* in English.

**Added:** The only pronunciation of the plural given by [Merriam-Webster Online](http://mw4.m-w.com/dictionary/tableau) is what could informally be written \TAB-loze. The American Heritage Dictionary, 4th ed. offers [tăb"lōz', tæ-blōz"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tableau) (where I’ve used " and ', respectively, for their bold and light symbols for primary and secondary stress). The Random House Dictionary (via [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tableau)) offers /tæˈbloʊz, ˈtæbloʊz/, the same two pronunciations in the opposite order, and has a sound file for the first one. The OED and the [Collins English Dictionary $-$ Complete and Unabridged](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tableau), which are the two British dictionaries readily available to me, offer both the /-z/ pronunciation and the pronunciation identical to the singular.

It appears, therefore, that in British usage the plural may (but need not) be pronounced identically to the singular; I have never heard this pronunciation in the U.S., however.

Comment: I have never heard the English pronunciation you describe. Where have you encountered it?

Comment: @Chris: I have no idea why you’ve not encountered it, since it’s the bog standard English pronunciation of the plural. Click on the sound file by *tableaux* [here](http://mw4.m-w.com/dictionary/tableau), for instance. In pseudo-phonetic spelling, the English plural is \ta-BLOZE\ or \TAB-loze\, both being acceptable.

Comment: +1 to Chris's comment. I have *always* heard the plural being pronounced exactly the same as the singular (though it may be different in the US).

Comment: Me too: I have never heard the x pronounced (but it may be because most people I have heard probably also speak French)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tableaux), tableaux is the British version of the plural, and gives tableaus as the US English version. Therefore, I would go with 'ta-blows'.

Comment: "Therefore, I would go with 'ta-blows'." -- assuming you are in the US...

Comment: In a mathematical context, using an -s would be weird.